# spectrum of operators

Tags: spectral-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T: X \rightarrow X$ is a bounded operator. The spectrum of $T$ is defined by 
$$\sigma(T) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}; \lambda I - T ~~ \mbox{is not invertible}\}$$
It is well known that $\sigma(T)$ is a bounded set.

Now, let  $S: X \rightarrow X$ be a bounded operator such that $S \neq 0$  and define the set 
$$\sigma_{S}(T) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}; \lambda S - T ~~ \mbox{is not invertible}\}$$.
My question is: the set $\sigma_{S}(T)$ is it bounded? and why?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. Take $H$ be a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis  $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Define $T$ to be the identity and
$$
Se_k=\frac{1}{k}e_k, \quad k\in\mathbb N.
$$
Then for $\lambda=k$, 
$$
(\lambda S-T)e_k=kSe_k-Te_k=e_k-e_k=0.
$$
Thus $\mathbb N\subset\sigma_S(T)$.